# React-Monaco-Editor: Not finding workers produced by monaco-editor-webpack-plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, monaco-editor

I'm trying to integrate the monaco editor into an existing react application.  I followed the installation steps from ([react-monaco-editor](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor)), but I don't get any syntax highlighting or autocomplete for typescript, consistent with the FAQ as if I hadn't set up the monaco-editor-webpack-plugin.

I have setup the plugin though.  I can see that the monaco-editor-webpack-plugin is dropping files along side my app.js, so I presume it is working:
[image]

It seems my issue is that react-monaco-editor is trying to pull these files from the wrong location.  If I load my page and open my network tab, I can see the following:

[image]

There are two problems:

1 - the paths are full paths on my system but should be relative paths - e.g.

```
http://127.0.0.1/dist/app/secured/49.js
```

2 - there is a slash missing between "secured" and "49.js" (secured49.js) and also for the other numeric files, but the editor.worker.js has the slash (weird).

So the question I'm hoping to answer is - how does react-monaco-editor determine the paths it will pull these files from, and is there a way I can influence the pathing?

Any help or recommendations would be much appreciated!  Some snippets of my code below in case helpful.

---

package.json:

```
"monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
"react-monaco-editor": "^0.26.2",
```

weback.config.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

process.noDeprecation = true;

const babel = {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }],
      ['jsx-control-statements'],
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind',
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { 'loose': true }]
    ],
    compact: true
  }
};

const config = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  mode: 'development', // Change to production on checkin
  context: settings.app(),
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      settings.app(),
      path.join(settings.project(), 'node_modules'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
    symlinks: true,
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', 'scss', 'less']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
      path.join(settings.project(), 'node_modules'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
    symlinks: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.(js|jsx)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-react'
              ],
              plugins: [
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind',
                ['jsx-control-statements'],
                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {'legacy': true}],
                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { 'loose': true }]
              ],
              compact: true
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
            mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
            mimetype: 'application/image/svg+xml'
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /-font\.otf(\?.+)?$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

index.js

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';

@observer
export default class TSEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      code: 'var name : string = "kyle";'
    };

    this.editorDidMount = this.editorDidMount.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(newValue, e) {
    console.log('onChange', newValue, e);
  }

  editorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    console.log('editorDidMount', editor);
    editor.focus();
  }

  render() {
    const code = this.state.code;
    const options = {
      selectOnLineNumbers: true
    };

    return (
      <MonacoEditor
        language="typescript"
        theme="vs-dark"
        value={code}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any messages in the browser console?

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for responding!  There are two errors in the console, both of which are related to failing to load JS files - secured4.js and secured53.js.  https://imgur.com/a/0Khd9kL

Those files exist, but not in the location monaco is looking for them.  I'm just not sure how to get monaco to look for them in the correct place.

Comment: Also to note, I've since removed the monaco-webpack-plugin and react-monaco-editor, and instead have followed instructions to use plain monaco and webpack from https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/docs/integrate-esm.md#option-2-using-plain-webpack.  The results are the same as before - except my editor has a white background.  It still tries to load 2 JS files that don't exist, and syntax highlighting / autocompletion does not work.

Comment: how are you serving the application?  I noticed in the error screenshot that your web server is serving the JavaScript files using mime type 'text/html', which will prevent the browser from consuming the files as you expect.  I suggest you update your question with some server code.

Comment: Those errors occur when monaco tries to load language files (e.g. 53.js) from the wrong path, resulting in a 404 (HTML).  If it were using the correct path, the MIME type would be accurate.  Any idea how monaco determines paths for dependencies?  I can control paths for workers via the getWorkerUrl function.  But for the language files (e.g. 53.js), monaco tries to load from http://127.0.0.1/Users/kylefox/go/src... which is wrong.  I'm just not sure how to control those paths.

To answer your question - using a golang based web server, but believe it's behaving correctly - as explained above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem caused by an incorrect publicPath in the output portion of my webpack configuration.

For anyone else with a similar issue, add a publicPath in your webpack configuration that gives the correct location of your web worker JS files.

Answer (score 1):

I my case... this did the trick... within webpack.config.js

```
  devServer: {
    https: true,
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "/dist/"
  },
  ...
  ..
  .
  plugins: [
      ...
      ..
      .
      new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        publicPath: "/dist/"
      })
  ]
```

available options are documented at https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin#options

Comment: The publicPath must end in "/". Otherwise it will fail.